I came across a set that is both closed and not closed. How is that possible?
Consider the set $S=\{x∈Q:-\sqrt2<x<\sqrt2\}$. Is it closed in $\Bbb Q$? Yes. $[-\sqrt2,\sqrt2]$ is a closed set in R and its intersection with $\Bbb Q$ gives us $S$.
However, isn't $\sqrt 2$ a limit point of $S$? Every neighbourhood of $\sqrt2$ will contain infinitely many rational numbers less than $\sqrt 2$ and hence $\sqrt 2$ is a limit point of $S$ which is not contained in $S$ so $S$ cannot be closed.
How is this possible? Is my reasoning flawed somewhere?

The others have answered well. But  I'd like to point out that every $w:  -\sqrt 2 < w< -\sqrt 2$ is also a limit point so any irrational in the range can make the argument.  (Example $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ is a limit point of $S$ [that is, when $S$ is viewed in $\mathbb R$ {and as a set in $\mathbb R$ $S$ is not closed}].) However as irrationals do not exist in $\mathbb Q$ at all, they can not be considered legitimate limit points when viewed in $\mathbb Q$.

$\sqrt{2}$ is not an element of $\mathbb{Q}$, so it can not be a limit point of $S$.
All topological notions, such as being a closed set or a limit point, are relative to the topological space you are working in. I assume you are using the following fact:

Let $X$ be a topological space. Then a subset $A \subseteq X$ is closed if and only if for every $p \in X$ that is a limit point of $A$ we have $p \in A$.

In your example, $S$ is closed (in $\mathbb{Q}$) because every $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ that is a limit point of $S$ belongs to $S$. You can not take $p = \sqrt{2}$ to fail this test, because $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$, and therefore it doesn't even make sense to say that $\sqrt{2}$ is a limit point of $S$ as long as you are asking about being closed in $\mathbb{Q}$.

As well, the OP seems to be using the fact that if as space $U$ is a subset of a space $X$ and $S$ is closed in $X$ then the intersection of $S$ and $U$ is close in regards to $U$ (but not nesc. in regards to $X$).   $S={x\in \mathbb Q| -\sqrt 2 < x < \sqrt 2}$ therefore is closed in $\mathbb Q$ (because $[-\sqrt 2, \sqrt2]$ is closed in $\mathbb R$) so no need to test if the limit points of $S$ are all in $S$. The OP was correct in that.    But $\sqrt 2$ in not a counter-example becuase $\sqrt 2$ is not in $\mathbb Q$ at all. That, as you point out, was the OP's mistake.

Right, I addressed the flawed part of the reasoning, but I could have also affirmed that the argument for the closedness of $S$ is correct. @fleablood

It's a standard way to get a closed set that has "open" bits.  Take a set that is closed in a superspace with limit points that are not in the subspace.  Intersect with the subspace and voila.  The set is closed but with "open" bits where the "missing" limit points no longer are!  And it's a standard way to find a cl/open set in $\mathbb Q$. ($\mathbb R$, with completeness, has only trivial cl/open sets).  Hope the OP is seeing how much fun math can be!

Firstly, when you talk about closed and open sets, you must specify the space and topology beforehand. Secondly, an open set can be closed at the same time(e.g. $\emptyset$), or not open nor closed at the same time(e.g.$[1,0)$ in $R$).
Here we consider the sets $R$ and $Q$, each with the usual metric topology.
In $R$, the set $S$ is not open, because $\exists a\in S, \nexists$ its neighborhood $N(a)$ s.t. $N(a)\subset S$. It is also not closed since the reasoning above works for its complement in $R$.
In $Q$, the set is open from the correct reasoning in the OP. It is also closed since that reasoning works as well for its complement in $Q$.
Edit:Fixed the mistake as in the comment of @Especially Lime

"In R, the set S is not closed, because ∃a∈S,∄ its neighborhood N(a) s.t. N(a)⊂S"
I did not understand this part. Could you elaborate? I have understood the reasoning otherwise.

@student Consider the point 0 in S (in R), for each neighborhood of 0 you can find a point in that neighborhood that doesn't belong to S.  Prove it yourself.

@MaYe I think the issue is that in that sentence you have "closed" and "open" swapped.

To me nothing in this answer seems relevant to the question. It is rather clear which topological space is considered. It is irrelevant that a set can be closed and open at the same time. The confusion is about a particular set being closed in $\mathbb{Q}$, so why address its closedness in $\mathbb{R}$ or its openness in $\mathbb{Q}$? Finally, the key mistake was not recognized and corrected - which is treating $\sqrt{2}$ as a limit point of $S$.
